# Match everything before a set of characters but if they aren't present then match everything

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a series of strings some of which have a year string at the end in the format `-2022`. I'm looking to match everything up to but excluding the `-` before 4 digit year string but if there is no year present then I would like to return the entire string. The following:

```
import re
x = "itf-m15-cancun-15-men-2022"
re.search(r"^.+?(?=-\d\d\d\d)", x).group()
```

Gets me `'itf-m15-cancun-15-men'` which I'm looking for. However, the following:

```
import re
x = "itf-m15-cancun-15-men"
re.search(r"^.+?(?=-\d\d\d\d)", x).group()
```

Errors as no result is returned. How do I capture everything up to but excluding the `-` before the 4 digit year string or return the whole string if the year string isn't present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add *[OR](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) [end](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)* `|$`  inside your lookahead:

```
^.+?(?=-\d{4}|$)
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OVZrQl/1)

Alternatively an [explicit greedy alternation](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#explicit_greed) could be used here [like in this demo](https://regex101.com/r/rbvE4y/1).

Comment: I'm not sure recommending a tempered greedy token is appropriate here. Your regex works fine and is simpler and more efficient.

Comment: @Nick I have changed the alternative to another solution that fits better here. Initially I thought it's important to have mention the *tempered greedy token* (efficiency depends on construction). I wonder if [eg this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/bQpPSD/1) would still count in there.

Comment: Much better alternative. Quite impressive increase in performance.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `(?=-\d\d\d\d)` conditional by adding a `?` after it. (Tested in JavaScript)

```
/^.+?(?=-\d\d\d\d)?$/
```

Comment: Making the lookahead optional simply allows the entire string to match. `"itf-m15-cancun-15-men-2022".match(/.+?(?=-\d\d\d\d)?$/)` returns `Array [ "itf-m15-cancun-15-men-2022" ]` not `"itf-m15-cancun-15-men"` as required